# Is there a short way to reference a question in the comments?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

When writing a comment, is there a short-way to make a hyperlink to a question, without copying and pasting its address (or its title + address)?

For instance, in order to refer to question #74, instead of writing:

```
[Is Smoothed Analysis used outside academia?]
(https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/74/is-smoothed-analysis-used-outside-academia/)
```

I'll just write

```
[CS.q.74]
```

or something like that?  If no such shortcut exists, what is the easiest way to achieve the above citation?

Comment: Use 'q/#': http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/74/

Comment: We *could* try and purchase the domain cs.se...

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there's no such shortcut.  There's a standing feature request on Meta.Stackexchange.com to have link to questions get converted to their title in comments, just like they do elsewhere.  See [Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394/160917).  You can upvote that feature reuqest if you want.  However, that feature request has been denied for performance reasons (seems unconvincing to me, but I don't get to make such decisions).

The shortest is to just write `http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/74` in your comment. Unfortunately, the title doesn't get automatically inserted, so the link looks a bit ugly.  There's no workaround that I know of: if you want to have the nice title, you have to insert it yourself, as you showed in your question. If you do that as an explicit link, you can omit the protocol and host name part of the URL (assuming you're referencing a question on the same site): `[Is Smoothed Analysis used outside academia?](/q/74)`.

You can use `/a/POST_NUMBER` to link to an answer. Click the `share` button below an answer to see its post number; the link is of the form `http://SITE/a/POST_NUMBER/USER_NUMBER`, but the second number is only used to track users who share links.

Comment: Shortest way if you want the title: [Is there a short way to reference a question in the comments?](/q/1124)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the `q/#` option, which is helpful. Would be great if [q/74] would have automatically brought the title. I'll vote for the feature request.

Comment: I usually use `[here](...)` or similar; there's usually no need to use the title (which, let's face it, is only sometimes really useful).

Comment: Uhh, thanks @Gilles. That's clever, if obvious if you think about it.

Comment: @Raphael Speaking as a reader, I really like to have the title so that I know what the link is to. (A full URL with the slug isn't as good as an explicit title because you can't easily see the URL on a mobile interface.)